# How do use EBean model inside main call from Play Framework2.1 Java

Tags: java, database, mocking, playframework-2.0

I would like to use EBean which comes with Play Framework 2.1 to setup some canned data. How when i run the main program I got some error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer()
```

And this is just a simple code.

```
package seeder.main;

import util.ProductBuilder;

import static play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.start;

public class DataSeeder {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        start(fakeApplication());

        new Product().save();
    }
}


public class Product extends Model {
    // properties
}
```

The code works fine in JUnit test but I want to run this code in Main so I can have all the designers run the program and get some canned data in db without using INSERT statement by hard to the database to design the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple days of pulling my hair, I got this working by adding

```
-javaagent:/${PROJECT_HOME}/lib/ebean-${VERSION{-agent.jar
```

which I have blogged it here.http://www.noppanit.com/run-ebean-entities-in-main-class-for-play-framework-java/

Comment: dead link in answer

Answer (score -1):

did you change your application.conf
you need to uncomment the ebean.default="models.*" and the Db lines in tha file

Comment: It looks like when I run that in Main method it doesn't read application.conf but if I run it from JUnit it works perfectly. So, I'm not sure if there's a difference between running from JUnit and main method.

Comment: tests classes usually extends WithApplication and have a setUp method